# Flutter & Cloud_Firestore. Convert Documents into Map

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I had tried the firebase realtime database. This is the method I used to extract the data from database and convert it back to a `Map`. However, lately I switched into cloud_firestore, and I had no idea how to perform the similar function. 
Please anyone help me.

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
const url = 'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products.json';
try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if (extractedData == null) {
    return;
  }
  final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
  extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    loadedProducts.add(Product(
      id: prodId,
      title: prodData['title'],
      description: prodData['description'],
      price: prodData['price'],
      isFavorite: prodData['isFavorite'],
      imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
    ));
  });
  _items = loadedProducts;
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  throw (error);
}
}
```

This is my attempt on modifying the code in order to work as the previous code:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetFoods() async {
try {
  final response = databaseReference.collection('Food').getDocuments();
  final extractedData = json.decode(response) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if (extractedData == null) {
    return;
  }
  final List<Foods> loadedFoods = [];
  extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    loadedFoods.add(FoodInfo(
      id: prodId,
      title: prodData['title'],
      description: prodData['description'],
      affordability: prodData['affordability'],
      image: prodData['image'],
      serviceTime: prodData['serviceTime'],
      cuisine: prodData['cuisine'],
    ));
  });
  _foods = loadedFoods;
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  throw (error);
}
}
```

Comment: And what happens with the new code?

Comment: The syntax of the cloud firestore is different from the real time database. I have no idea how to extract the data from cloudfirestore into the map format as the first code does.